# How to use two different styles for two elements in a single table cell in prawn pdf generation rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I am using prawn to generate PDF file in Rails.

I want to create a table cell which has the same property as this table cell in HTML:

```
<td>Invoice # <strong>IN0002</strong></td>
```

My code in Prawn is like this:

```
make_cell(:content => "#{"IN#%06d" % @invoice.id}", font_style: :bold)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used `make_cell`, but I know you can do it directly in the table declaration using the cell style `inline_format` option set to true.

I create here a 2*2 table with only the first cell filled in, and I suppose `IN0002` is the invoice id (I know it's not true but I let you modify this part):

```
table [["Invoice <strong>#{@invoice.id}</strong>", ""], 
       ["", ""]],
       cell_style: { inline_format: true }
```

You will find more information in this [documentation](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf).